# Laravel: GlobalController with Auth

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

i will call a Controller all times. It is my GlobalController. I will use the Auth, and DB Function.

I doing this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Auth;
use DB;


class GlobalController extends Controller
{

      function user_in_party() {
        // Get the logged user
        $user = Auth::user();
        print_R($user);
        exit;
      }

}
```

Now i call this from my Web.php (Routes) like this but i don't become the Authed user back why?

```
app('App\Http\Controllers\GlobalController')->user_in_party();
```

Can u help me? Or say me a better Solution?

Comment: What is the exact use case you are trying to achieve by doing this?

Comment: I will use always my function in the index.blade.php

Comment: Basically having a variable always sent to [all views](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/views#sharing-data-with-all-views) ?

Comment: Yes, i need a view variable in all my blade files. But i need informations from my database and i need the auth user->id.

Comment: i give you another way if you like to use class as global class.can you like to use another way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using this Instead you can just Call

```
Auth::user();
```

its all global once a user is logged in you can get its details via `Auth`